# why do i have an error 500 when i start odoo?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

When I start odoo I see the following error:

```
2021-07-13 10:16:03.554 CEST [13676] ERROR: The relationship "ir_module_module" does not exist 28 2021-07-13 10:16:03.554 CEST [13676] STATEMENT: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base'
```

Comment: It seems that the table `ir_module_module` doesn't exist.

Comment: That's a typical error when the database creation wasn't working right. So maybe your database is corrupted or wasn't created fully.